# Import models function

Tags: python, django

I created a models within my page but when I attempted to run the page I received an error response

```
celery_beat_1    |     class ClassManager(models.Manager):
celery_beat_1    | NameError: name 'models' is not defined
```

I searched for fixes to this error online and most of the responses said to implement the

```
import from django.db import models
```

function. However, this is something I already have configured in my models page. Any idea on how to proceed forward?

Comment: It's `from django.db import models`. There's no `import` on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

You should import `models` from django in models.py.

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass
```

You can check more information in django documentation itself:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#quick-example

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the models in wrong way format, so you have to use -

```
from django.db import models
```

rather than using

```
import from django.db import models
```